# How do you calculate a time difference between 2 different rows in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to calculate the difference between 2 date fields in the same table, however the values are not in the same row. An example table is below

```
ID   Cust_ID   Code      Order_Time           Delivery_Time      Duration
 1     4       Order   01/01/15 14:15
 2     5       order   02/02/15 18:30
 3     4       deliver                         03/02/15 18:15    28:00
 4     6       order    04/02/15 16:22
```

I need to calculate the time taken (Duration) in hours to deliver the order by subtracting the order time for Cust_ID 4 from the delivery_time for this customer.  In the example above I have entered the figure as 28 hours.

Comment: If the records are coded as to whether they are a delivery or an order, why are `Delivery_Time` and `Order_Time` different fields.  Shouldn't they just be `Time`?

Comment: What if *the same customer* (so Cust_Id is the same) made *several* orders?

Comment: @Tripp Kinetics: should not the question be - why the delivery_time was not updated under "delivery_time" in the order record itself ? (in other words, what is the meaning of "delivery_time" for an order, if not this ?)

Comment: @Tripp Kinetics yes they should if i made the DB but i just work on this DB I did not design it.

Comment: @Veverke It's a different way of looking at the same problem.  But it is indeed the same problem.  This schema design doesn't make much sense.  (At least to me.)

Comment: @HardLeeWorking This might be a good time to fix it.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko for the sake of this example a customer does not have more than 1 order. the actual DB measure callbacks to customers so once a callback is complete they get a new ID for any future calls,

Comment: @tripp kinetics "not in your remit" was the response, they just want the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t._cust_id, MAX(order_time) order_time, MAX(delivery_time) delivery_time, MAX(delivery_time) - MAX(order_time) as diff_time
FROM   yourTable t
WHERE  t.cust_id = 4
GROUP BY t.cust_id
```

or

```
SELECT
      o.order_time, d.delivery_time, d.delivery_time - o.order_time as diff_time
FROM  yourTable o, yourTable d
WHERE LOWER(o.code) = 'order'
and   LOWER(d.code) = 'deliver'
AND   o.cust_id = d.cust_id
GROUP BY o._cust_id
```

----- for updating the table -----
can you check if the following works ? I am not sure...

```
UPDATE 
(
    SELECT
          o.order_time, t.delivery_time order_delivery_time, d.delivery_time, d.delivery_time - o.order_time as diff_time
    FROM  yourTable o, yourTable d
    WHERE LOWER(o.code) = 'order'
    and   LOWER(d.code) = 'deliver'
    AND   o.cust_id = d.cust_id
    GROUP BY o._cust_id
) t
SET
  t.order_delivery_time = t.diff_time
```

Comment: i need this to update the table rather than provide an output of solutions, so the duration column can be queried at a later date by different departments. also there are multiple customers so hard coding for one customer ID doesnt help with a long term solution,

Comment: @ Veverke just working it through now, i didnt realise you had given the same table 2 aliases ( o. and t.) just realised this was possible. I will update when I get it to run. thanks

Comment: @HardLeeWorking: that's how you perform a self-join.

Comment: I didnt know tis was possible, this has helped me more in the long run that just with this query. thanks.

Comment: @HardLeeWorking: cool, that's what this is all about... we all have been helped, and we remember we were in need... after taking, there's the time of giving in return ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Veverke who really helped me with not only this query but a better understanding of what I can do in SQL (self-join).

This is the SELECT query that worked:

```
SELECT
       d.delivery_time - o.order_time as diff_time
FROM  yourTable o, yourTable d
WHERE o.code = 'order'
AND   d.code = 'deliver'
AND   o.cust_id = d.cust_id
GROUP BY o.cust_id, d.delivery_time,o.order_time
ORDER BY o.cust_id;
```